# command terminated with non-zero exit code: Error executing in Docker Container: 137 (Mongo Manager)

Tags: mongodb, docker, openshift

Based on this guide:

https://docs.opsmanager.mongodb.com/current/tutorial/install-simple-test-deployment/

I am trying to run MongoDB and MongoDB Ops Manager in OpenShift. I have manged to *dockerize* both MongoDB and MongoDB Ops Manager and MongoDB is running successfully listening on port 27017 and on all interfaces:

```
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0
```

I also manage to get MongoDB Ops Manager *initialized* meaning the below steps complete successfully (including connecting to my mongodb instance):

```
Generating new Ops Manager private key...
Starting pre-flight checks
Successfully finished pre-flight checks

Migrate Ops Manager data
   Running migrations...[  OK  ]
Start Ops Manager server
   Instance 0 starting..................[  OK  ]
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
Starting pre-flight checks
Successfully finished pre-flight checks

Start Backup Daemon...[  OK  ]
```

but then it suddenly fails with:

```
tail -f /opt/mongodb/mms/logs/mms0.log
...
2019-04-25T14:30:42.616+0000 [main] INFO  com.xgen.svc.mms.svc.ping.PingRequest$Observable [Observable.java.addObserver:19] - Registering observer: class com.xgen.svc.mms.svc.ping.TotalStorageCacheSvc
2019-04-25T14:30:42.618+0000 [main] INFO  com.xgen.svc.mms.svc.ping.PingRequest$Observable [Observable.java.addObserver:19] - Registering observer: class com.xgen.svc.mms.svc.ping.NDSAutoScalingIngestionSvc
2019-04-25T14:31:00.536+0000 [main] INFO  com.xgen.svc.core.ServerMain [ServerMain.java.setUpProxyServer:620] - Started queryable backup proxy server on port 25999
2019-04-25T14:31:00.537+0000 [ProxyServer-25999] INFO  backup.jobs.queryable.ProxyServer.25999 [ProxyServer.java.run:96] - Waiting for Proxy Server PEM File to be specified in the configuration
2019-04-25T14:31:00.559+0000 [main] INFO  com.xgen.svc.core.ServerMain [ServerMain.java.start:537] - Started mms at build ed64653d5f@on-prem-4.0 in: 51476 (ms)
command terminated with non-zero exit code: Error executing in Docker Container: 137
```

And with additional logging with DEBUG level enabled:

```
2019-04-27T13:46:35.035+0000 [job-consumer-214366356] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.protocol.command [SLF4JLogger.java.debug:56] - Sending command {findandmodify : BsonString{value='data.jobsProcessor'}} to database mmsdbjobs on connection [connectionId{localValue:13, serverValue:31}] to server mongo-db:27017
2019-04-27T13:46:35.036+0000 [job-consumer-214366356] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.protocol.command [SLF4JLogger.java.debug:56] - Command execution completed
2019-04-27T13:46:35.476+0000 [mms_QuartzSchedulerThread] DEBUG org.quartz.simpl.PropertySettingJobFactory [SimpleJobFactory.java.newJob:51] - Producing instance of Job 'DEFAULT.dbRollupSchedulerJob', class=com.xgen.svc.core.svc.cron.SimpleJob
2019-04-27T13:46:35.477+0000 [mms_QuartzSchedulerThread] DEBUG org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread [QuartzSchedulerThread.java.run:291] - batch acquisition of 1 triggers
2019-04-27T13:46:35.477+0000 [mms_Worker-31] DEBUG org.quartz.core.JobRunShell [JobRunShell.java.run:201] - Calling execute on job DEFAULT.dbRollupSchedulerJob
2019-04-27T13:46:35.478+0000 [mms_Worker-31] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.protocol.command [SLF4JLogger.java.debug:56] - Sending command {count : BsonString{value='config.customers'}} todatabase mmsdbconfig on connection [connectionId{localValue:13, serverValue:31}] to server mongo-db:27017
2019-04-27T13:46:35.480+0000 [mms_Worker-31] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.protocol.command [SLF4JLogger.java.debug:56] - Command execution completed
2019-04-27T13:46:35.481+0000 [mms_Worker-31] DEBUG com.xgen.svc.core.svc.cron.CronJob [CronJob.java.canProceed:47] - Not proceeding with CronJob dbRollupScheduler. No Projects.
command terminated with non-zero exit code: Error executing in Docker Container: 137
```

But not much of help to what is causing this termination of the docker container.

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Notice it works fine when using plain docker on my local ubuntu box (machine having 8 GB RAM).

**EDIT:**

Based on below suggestion I have also tried to set the following resources in the deployment config for the Mongo Manager:

```
  kind: DeploymentConfig
  metadata:
    name: ${NAME}
  spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
      app: ${NAME}
    strategy:
      type: Recreate  
          ...
        containers:
        - name: ${NAME}
          image: ${IMAGE}
          ports:
           - containerPort: 8080
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 8
              memory: 15Gi
            requests:
              cpu: 8
              memory: 15Gi
```

But still same result.

And the Dockerfile

```
FROM centos:latest
RUN yum update -y && \
    yum install -y openssl iproute nano net-tools    

COPY run.sh /
RUN chmod 750 /run.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/run.sh"]
```

and `run.sh` is:

```
#!/bin/bash
export TERM="xterm"

curl -k https://downloads.mongodb.com/on-prem-mms/rpm/mongodb-mms-4.0.10.50461.20190403T1841Z-1.x86_64.rpm -o tmp/mongodb-mms-4.0.10.50461.20190403T1841Z-1.x86_64.rpm

cd /tmp \
    && rpm -ivh mongodb-mms-4.0.10.50461.20190403T1841Z-1.x86_64.rpm \
    && rm mongodb-mms-4.0.10.50461.20190403T1841Z-1.x86_64.rpm

cp /opt/configmap/conf-mms/conf-mms.properties /opt/mongodb/mms/conf/
cp /opt/configmap/mms/mms.conf /opt/mongodb/mms/conf/
cp /opt/configmap/logback/logback.xml /opt/mongodb/mms/conf/
chown -R mongodb-mms:mongodb-mms /opt/mongodb/mms/
/bin/bash /opt/mongodb/mms/bin/mongodb-mms start
```

Where files in /opt/configmap are mounted from configmaps.

Comment: I'm about 99% sure that `137` is an "out of memory" error. Try increasing the pods memory limits.

Comment: I have tried to increase that as well but same result, see updated post.

Comment: Hmm, other than OOM, it can also mean a `SIGKILL`, so OpenShift might be killing it. Is there anything in the events log for the project? Is Ops Manager a long running process?

Comment: No nothing else in the event log, it takes a bit of time to start-up (locally) but nothing unusual - compared to my other applications. I have tried to de-compile com.xgen.svc.core.ServerMain but exactly that class cannot be de-compiled so I am in the dark here.

Comment: Care to share your Dockerfile?

Comment: Updated post with dockerfile and entry script

Comment: Just FYI, but the doc that you linked to recommends `System Memory 15 GB`

Comment: Yep I did read that, but as I also wrote I managed to get it up and running with just 8 GB on my laptop. Further when I look at the metrics in open shift of the pod while I starts up it’s far from consuming that amount

Comment: Yeah, I seem to be able to replicate everything you're doing, but I'm erroring out in the same place. I wish I could help you further, but I have no idea what I'm doing wrt the Ops Manager. Sorry

Comment: You can confirm whether it is being OOM [out of memory] killed, using this docker command: `docker inspect <container_id>  -f '{{ json .State.OOMKilled }}'`   (replace `<container_id>` with the name or ID of the container)

Comment: In openshift I don't have access to the docker command like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no suggestions/answers have been written on how to successfully dockerize and deploy Mongo Ops Manager in OpenShift doing a *plain* non container installation seems to be the only solution as of now, e.g.:

https://docs.opsmanager.mongodb.com/current/tutorial/install-simple-test-deployment/

Answer (score 2):

I think you'd be better off following the docs to [Install MongoDB Enterprise Kubernetes Operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/kubernetes-operator/stable/tutorial/install-k8s-operator/) and then [Install MongoDB via Kubernetes](https://docs.opsmanager.mongodb.com/current/tutorial/nav/manage-hosts-kubernetes/index.html).

It's the more modern and preferred method to install inside OpenShift. This should take care of most of the complexity outlined in your question.

Comment: Ops Manager is not really designed to be containerized. You would have a single OM installation for your entire organisation's MongoDB deployments, so I feel it probably should be outside of OpenShift and only the Nodes themselves inside pods

Comment: My original question was about how to install/containerize Mongo Ops Manager in OpenShift not how to install the kubernets Operator and utilize that assuming a fully functional Ops Manager. So you comment above should have been the answer I believe.